# Using JPA as a caching mechanism?

Tags: java, caching, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm new to JPA, so forgive this question if this is pretty standard functionality, but can you use JPA without having a database and basically use it as a cache to store objects across your application? If so, is that standard practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use JPA with an [in memory database](http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/InMemoryBackEndPrimer) so it would effectively just be a cache, yes.  Using it 'without a database' at all would take huge amounts of work to build a custom JPA provider that works against whatever your storage is.  If it's truly a full JPA implementation that simply leaves off the 'Persistent' part, you'd spend months if not years alone just reinventing the wheel to implement the query language against your non-RDBMS cache and so forth.

I haven't worked everywhere, but personally would certainly not file such a setup under 'standard practices.' :)

Answer (score 1):

JPA is just an API implemented by few major players like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) and [OpenJPA](http://openjpa.apache.org/) (so called *persistence providers*). All these libraries implement object-relational mapping and are focused towards database.

I don't really get your motivation but you can:

- use in-memory database like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) and any persistence provider
- use *de-facto* standard caching solutions like [EhCache](http://ehcache.org/) or [JCache](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107) API abstraction
- implement your own persistence provider implementing JPA. The scariest and worst solution.

Comment: Thanks, it was definitely more of a theoretical, "can you do this question?" I'm aware of EhCache and Memcache, etc.., but it was really just curiosity to see if it was possible.